# Is it permissible for Muslims to believe in Chakras?

Tags: other-religions

[Chakras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra) are said to be whirling pools of energy in our body according to Hinduism/Buddhism. It is said that these chakras can be open, closed or overactive, and depending on their status, they could affect people in different ways. Is there anything in Islam that refuse or accept this? Can a Muslim believe in chakras? (Bonus question: is it ok in Islam to meditate?)

Comment: well reading around the net tell me the different poses in a namaz are different ways of activating chakras. im not too sure about its authenticity, i will research and then post an answer

Answer (score 3):

Chakras aren't entirely a religious concept. One may need faith to believe in them, however that would depend on the person; in some cultures, there are cases where representations of chakras actually show results in some way.

And as for meditation, it is allowed and is practiced in Islam. *Dhikr*, in a sense, is a form of meditation, since you sit and dedicate time out of your life directly to God. There are some who focus during this so greatly with all their heart that they cry during *dhikr* because they feel God's Blessing. This is in fact considered a form of meditation.

In addition, not all meditation is religious — it can be medical, and it has been proven to improve health in some areas — so you're not doing anything wrong if you meditate. There are many forms of meditation out there, and I suggest you look some up.  You'd be surprised at how many there are.

Comment: May I add this to your answer that meditation (_and all the philosophies behind it_) if is seen as an alternative to a heavenly religion it is forbidden but otherwise it can be practiced like a cure for psychological diseases like sport serves the body for its health? Although as you already said Islam itself has introduced a number of practices some of them being very similar to meditations!

Comment: I guess you are wrongly mixing *Dhikr* and the OP's question about *Chakra*. I don't see any similarity.